# forgo -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Here the author is comparing two image compression formats, namely, the JPEG format and the GIF format:

> The moral of this tale is that more often than not, you’ll want to retain as much photographic realism in your inline images as possible, and you’ll **forgo** a little extra file size for that privilege, whereas for your background images, you’ll likely need less realism and will be working with larger blocks of color or small gradient areas, and will therefore need the GIF format.

I know that the verb construction *forgo something* basically means *to go without something* but in the context of this big sentence, it doesn't really make much sense, if you think about it for a second. If you're using the JPEG format, you can't forgo a little extra file size (you will not go without it, on the contrary, you will go with it!) because JPEG image files are usually larger than the same images compressed with the GIF format. There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Probably the author meant "a little extra memory" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything. The writer probably made a mistake, perhaps during an editing pass when they decided to adjust their wording and didn't make all the necessary fixes. What (s)he really means is something like "forgo a slightly better file size" — but I can't think of a non-awkward way to phrase that.

If I were the writer, I'd probably forgo *forgo*, and change it to "accept a little extra file size".

Comment: I might say you will "*incur*" a little extra file size...

Comment: @Jim: "Forgo" and "accept" both imply *intent*, whereas "incur" does not. (One can, for example, "accidentally incur" a penalty.) So I don't think that "incur" conveys everything that the writer was trying to convey.

Comment: I see your point, but I wouldn't read too much into the author's intent, they clearly don't even know how to use *forgo* correctly.

Comment: @Jim: Dunno what you mean by "clearly". As you can see from my answer, I think they *do* know how to use *forgo* correctly, and simply made a mistake. (Have you never made an editing mistake?)

Comment: Maybe, but I think it's sloppy writing.  Notice in the next sentence where it's talking about less realism, larger blocks of color "and will therefore **need** the GIF format."  While I agree that GIF may be better suited, one hardly **needs** the GIF format.